# Django request.session.get() returns None across different view classes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-sessions

I am working on a Django project and I'm encountering an issue with session variables. I set a session variable in one view, but when I try to access it in another view, it returns None.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

In my `LoginVerification` view:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class LoginVerification(APIView):
    def post(request):
        # ... login logic ...

        # If login is successful, I store the AWS access key in the session
        request.session['aws_access_key'] = 'your-access-key'

        return Response({"message": "Login successful"})
```

In my `BucketSize` view:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class BucketSize(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # Here, I try to retrieve the AWS access key from the session
        aws_access_key = request.session.get('aws_access_key')

        if aws_access_key is None:
            return Response({'status': 'error', 'error': 'No AWS access key found in session.'})

        # ... remaining logic ...

        return Response({'status': 'success', 'bucketsize': bucketsize, 'unit': unit})
```

In the BucketSize view, request.session.get('aws_access_key') is always returning None, even though I have set it in the LoginVerification view.

This is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'server',
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    

]
```

I have checked the following:

The session variable is being set: The code in the LoginVerification view is running without errors.

> 1. The session has not expired: I'm testing the BucketSize view
>    immediately after the LoginVerification view.
> 2. I have not cleared my cookies: I am consistently using the same
>    browser session for testing.
> 3. I am using the same browser session: I'm not switching browsers or
>    going into incognito mode.

I would like to know why request.session.get('aws_access_key') is returning None in the BucketSize view, and how I can resolve this issue.

EDIT: This is my rest framework settings --

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think storing your access key anywhere else than secrets is good idea

Comment: Yes i know. I will be encrypting it later. @dawid.pawlowski

Answer (score 0):

to fix you issue you need to call the **.save()** method after assigning the key. You can do it as follows in your `LoginVerification`:

**EDIT:**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class LoginVerification(APIView):
    def post(self, request): # self parameter was missing from the function (it can be anything but in python we usually use `self`)
        # ... login logic ...

        # If login is successful, I store the AWS access key in the session
        request.session['aws_access_key'] = 'your-access-key'

        request.session.save()  # Need to save this

        return Response({"message": "Login successful"})
```

Though it is not a good idea to store access keys in session variables

Comment: I tried this. Still doesn't work. The output still comes as None

Comment: Can you share your REST_FRAMEWORK settings? Are you using session authentication or token authentication with your REST_FRAMEWORK?

Comment: I have updated my question. please have a look @SimbaOG

Comment: Hey, I just noticed it. Your function is missing the self parameter for the class, that's why the request object is not loading. I have edited the answer for your reference.

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem. :( im sorry

Comment: Can you check what you are receiving in request object? Also check the available methods using `dir(request)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254847/discussion-between-simbaog-and-suprava).